# Repaint teleports my graphic instead of smoothly moving it

Tags: java, swing, custom-painting

So in my code I repaint my graphic in the desired direction when I press one of the W,A,S,or D keys. Instead of the graphic smoothly moving from left to right or up and down, it just goes invisible and sometimes becomes visible again, but it will always become visible if I let go of the key that I am pressing. I have created the exact same program on another computer and this issue does not appear, but on my personal computer it is always there.

```
    import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class mainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static int px,py,pwid,phei,ex,ey,ewid,ehei,speed,ppx,ppy;
    /**
     * Creates new form mainFrame
     */
    public mainFrame() {
        initComponents();
        px = 150;py = 150;pwid = 50;phei = 50;speed = 10000;

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics player = (Graphics)g;
        player.drawRect(px, py, pwid, phei);

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        int keycode = evt.getKeyCode();
        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_D){    
            repaint(px++*speed);
        }if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_A){    
            repaint(px--*speed);
        }if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_W){    
            repaint(py--*speed);
        }if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_S){    
            repaint(py++*speed);
        }
        if(px >= 400-42 || px <= 0+42){
            px = px - 1;
        }else if(py >= 300-42 || py <= 0+42){
            System.out.println("You Cant go there");
        }
    }                               

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new mainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not really the idea behind `repaint(int)`, instead, you should have a "game loop" which updates the current state of the game and schedules a repaint.

Also, you really should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers because, as you've discovered, they aren't double buffered, which can cause flickering when they are updated. `JFrame` also contains a bunch of other components which, because of the way painting works, can be painted independently of your container, meaning that they can find what you've previously painted

Instead, start with something like `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting within it, then add this panel to an instance of a `JFrame`

You should also avoid using `KeyListener` for a number of reasons (focus related issues been the major one) and instead prefer the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Ok so seeing as I have a very low level of knowledge towards Java and I'm trying to somewhat comprehend, how to make a simple game. Would there be anyway to make what I'am doing work a,or would I have to completely restart and create a JPanel focused program.

Comment: Well, you could spend a lot of time reinventing the wheel and implementing your own double buffering solution, or you could use the available functionality that the API provides, that's up to you. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [ Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a simple solution for a "game loop"

Answer (score 0):

Take your "player" object and make an explicit class for it called Player

example:

```
class Player extends JComponent {
    //unique player fields here

    /**
     * Method to draw this particular component.
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // insert content of your paint method here
    }
}
```

And when you want to add the player component to your JFrame use:

```
this.getContentPane().add(new Player());
```

MadProgrammer covered the things I wanted to say regarding keyboard input, and lack of a game loop.

Comment: I thank you very much on the help towards what I am doing wrong. I will probably have other question's down the road but for now I will try to implement your current suggestions. Thank you again.

Comment: So for the this.getContentPaint().add(new Player()); it does not run anything from my Player class. Is this because I'm just being a dunce or something else. Also sorry to be such a nuisance.

Comment: try debugging within the paintComponent() method. The JFrame should be trying to paint each subcomponent so the paintComponent method of Player will be called so long as JFrame is painting it's components.

Comment: Listen to what MadProgrammer has said about the "game loop", you need something that is continually running and drawing components